# Como estilizar o ícone "limpar" do input type search?

Tags: css, html5, css3

Preciso de um meio de estilizar o ícone × que fica ao final do `input[type="search"]`.

O input type search ao focar no elemento, o mesmo apresenta um × caso o mesmo tenha um valor preenchido.

Exemplo:

[image: Input type search botão de limpar]

Eu percebi que ao estiliar o input `search`, muitas vezes esse "xizinho" some.

Como eu posso fazer para estilizá-lo e ainda preservá-lo no `input[type="search"]`?

Answer (score 5):

Talvez uma solução seja justamente o contrario, desabilitar o ícone e usar um background personalizado, veja:

```js
(function() {
  document.querySelector(".fundo").onclick = function() {
    document.querySelector(".fundo").value = "";
  };
}());
```

```css
input[type="search"]::-webkit-search-decoration,
input[type="search"]::-webkit-search-cancel-button,
input[type="search"]::-webkit-search-results-button,
input[type="search"]::-webkit-search-results-decoration {
  display: none;
}

.fundo {
  background: url(http://www.nepneuro.com.br/site/img/fechar.svg) no-repeat scroll 98%;
  z-index: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input name="teste" type="search" class="fundo">
```

Comment: Aí vou ter que colocar uma imagem e um javascript para uma coisa que já faz nativamente :\

Comment: Duas sugestões se me permite, troque o display:none por visibility:hidden; e faça o evento aplicar uma classe que adiciona o x, então ficará perfeito :) ... (ps: eu ainda não testei se visibility funciona)

Answer (score 3):

Neste caso o que você deseja é o [::-webkit-search-cancel-button](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::-webkit-search-cancel-button).

Ele é o pseudo elemento CSS que representa o "botão de cancelar".

Para estilizar o mesmo você pode fazer algo parecido com isso:

```css
#Search {
  width: 480px;
  height: 49px;
  border: 3px solid black;
  padding-left: 48px;
  padding-top: 1px;
  font-size: 22px;
  color: blue;
  background-image: url('images/search.jpg');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
  outline: 0;
}

#Search::-webkit-search-cancel-button {
  position: relative;
  right: 20px;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  height: 20px;
  width: 20px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<input id="Search" name="Search" type="search" placeholder="Search" />
```

Vale lembrar que você pode ter problemas de compatibilidades com ele, como apresentado pelo site de [Desenvolvedores da Mozilla (MDN)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::-webkit-search-cancel-button).

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Caso queira mais detalhes, pode ver [esta resposta do SOen.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20804207/4843158)

Comment: Opa, gostei da sua resposta, muito bom. Pena que ainda só o  Webkit tem essa estilização. Implementações de CSS sempre decepcionando :\. +1

Answer (score 3):

**Sim**, o tal `x` (botão de cancelar) some se o mouse não estiver por cima do elemento e não tem como preserva-lo visível, eu até cheguei a encontrar um [artigo](http://davidbcalhoun.com/2012/more-fun-with-webkit-pseudoelements-webkit-search-cancel-button-or-pseudoclass-inception/) sobre customizar o botão de cancelar, mas se ler com atenção notará que fala de iOS, testando no Chrome/Opera notará que não funciona e também note que ele mesmo afirma que isto não chega a ser uma boa solução e que é preferível usar algum javascript que auxilie.

A única maneira seria simular este botão usando [javascript](/questions/tagged/javascript), ou algum framework javascript

### Exemplo cross-platform

```js
var fields = document.querySelectorAll(".field");

for (var i = 0, j = fields.length; i < j; i++) {
    cancelButtonEvents(fields[i]);
}

function updateVisibility(field, btn, timer) {
    timer && clearTimeout(timer);
    timer = setTimeout(function () {
        if (field.value != "") {
            btn.classList.add("visible");
        } else {
            btn.classList.remove("visible");
        }
    }, 10);
}

function cancelButtonEvents(field) {
    var realField = field.querySelector(".main-field");
    var btn = field.querySelector(".cancel");
    var timer;
    
    btn.onclick = function () {
        realField.value = "";
        updateVisibility(realField, btn, timer);
    };
    
    realField.onkeydown = function () {
         updateVisibility(realField, btn, timer);
    };
}
```

```css
.field {
    display: inline-block;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
}

.field input {
    border: none;
    background: transparent;
    vertical-align: middle;
}

.field a.cancel {
    visibility: hidden;
    text-decoration: none;
    padding: 5px;
}

.field a.visible {
    visibility: visible;
}
```

```html
<div class="field">
    <input class="main-field" type="text" value="">
    <a class="cancel" href="javascript:void(0);">x</a>
</div>
```

### Exemplo com [type=search] real (somente Webkit/Blink)

Me baseando na resposta do [Marcelo](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/206542/3635) criei um exemplo que oculta o botão `x` com `opacity` e aplica uma imagem de fundo para trocar simular o `x`, claro que depende um pouco de JavaScript como citei anteriormente:

> note que usei o `:not([disabled]):not([readonly])` para evitar que elementos com atributo/propriedade `disabled` ou `readonly` exibam o "botão simulado"

```js
var searchFields = document.querySelectorAll("input[type=search]");

for (var i = 0, j = searchFields.length; i < j; i++) {
    cancelButtonEvents(searchFields[i]);
}

function updateVisibility(field, btn, timer) {
    timer && clearTimeout(timer);
    timer = setTimeout(function () {
        if (field.value != "") {
            field.classList.add("no-empty-search");
        } else {
            field.classList.remove("no-empty-search");
        }
    }, 10);
}

function cancelButtonEvents(field) {
    updateVisibility(field);
    
    field.onkeydown = function () {
        updateVisibility(field);
    };
    field.onchange = function () {
        updateVisibility(field);
    };
    field.oninput = function () {
        updateVisibility(field);
    };
}
```

```css
::-webkit-search-cancel-button {
    opacity: 0;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.no-empty-search:not([disabled]):not([readonly]) {
    background: url(http://www.nepneuro.com.br/site/img/fechar.svg) no-repeat scroll 98%;
}
```

```html
Vazio:
<input name="teste1" type="search" value="">
<br><br>

Pré-preenchido:
<input name="teste2" type="search" value="Olá mundo!">
<br><br>

Desabilitado:
<input name="teste3" type="search" value="desabilitado enquanto consulta via Ajax por exemplo" disabled>
<br><br>

Somente leitura:
<input name="teste4" type="search" value="leitura" readonly>
```