# Como customizar o X do input pesquisa

Tags: javascript, html, css

[imagem do meu campo de pesquisa](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jWeId.png)

```
.campoPesquisa{
    position: fixed;
    top: calc(0px + 70px);
    width: 100%;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    height: 70px;
    background-color: var(--fundo-nav-light);
}
#campoSearch{
    width: 90%;
    height: 50px;
    border-radius: 1rem;
    border: none;
    background-color: var(--cor-campoPesquisa);
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 1.1rem;
    color: var(--cor-texto);
    appearance: none;

}

        <div class="campoPesquisa">
            <input type="search" name="" id="campoSearch" placeholder="">
        </div>
```

Comment: Seria interessante postar o HTML também, para termos certeza do que é esse X.

Comment: Note que só funciona em navegadores como Safari e Chrome, se precisar de todos, como Firefox, e até navegadores antigos, vai precisar fazer algo próprio com JavaScript ao invés de usar type=search, exemplo: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/206553/3635